# Maven: Easily find where included dependency is used in project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependency-management

Suppose I have a partial maven project pom `dependency:tree` output like this

```
[INFO] +- com.example:library:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.example.cache:some-cache:jar:2.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.example.core:core:jar:1.0.1:compile
```

Is there an easy method (or method via IntelliJ) for determining which, if any, classes from some-cache.jar or core.jar are used in the project? I would like to exclude the unnecessary dependencies in the tree.

I am aware of the `dependency:analyze` method for finding unused dependencies, but I have a secondary goal of relocating or rewiring any in-use classes from these dependencies so that I can eventually exclude them.

IntelliJ supports some features that could accomplish this with time, but projects are quite large (several thousand classes) and searching for usages of each 1 by 1 borders on extremely tedious.

Thanks for your attention to my question.